# Fectch uncommon ID between two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables and I need to fetch if any one ID is not present in the table 2. I tried the query but its not giving the correct result. Kindly suggest.

**TABLE 1**

[image]

**TABLE 2**

[image]

**Output Should be:** Because Release ID and purchase ID is not present in both the columns.

[image]

**QUERY Tried :**

```
SELECT T1_ID 
FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2
ON t1.RELEASEID=t2.RELEASEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 t3
ON t1.PURCHASEID=t3.PURCHASEID
WHERE IFNULL(T2.RELEASEID,'') ='' OR IFNULL(T3.PURCHASEID,'')=''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
select * from t1
where not exists (select 1 from t2
where t1.releaseid =t2.releaseid or t1.purchaseid =t2.purchaseid)
```

You can also use `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
select t1.*
  from t1 left join t2
    on t1.releaseid =t2.releaseid or t1.purchaseid =t2.purchaseid
 where t2.t2_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from t2
                  where t2.releaseid = t1.releaseid
                 ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t2
                  where t2.purchaseid = t1.purchaseid
                 );
```

This should work regardless of whether `?` is really a string or is supposed to represent `NULL`.

Note:  This can take advantage of indexes on `t2(releaseid)` and `t2(purchaseid)`, which can be a big boost to performance on larger data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where 
    (t1.release_id = '?' and t2.purchase_id = '?')
    or not exists (
        select 1
        from table2 t2
        where t1.release_id in ('?', t2.release_id)
          and t1.purchase_id in ('?', t2.purchase_id)
)
```

If the question mark is supposed to represent `null` values, you can just replace all instances of `= '?'` with `is null`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let me know if it works.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT '1' FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE1 .RELEASEID=TABLE2.RELEASEID OR  TABLE1 .PURCHASEID=TABLE2.PURCHASEID);
```